# learning mongodb and importing json file but where do I save the json file?

Tags: mongodb, import, command

I'm trying to learn MongoDB for the first time in a Windows 10 environment.

I found tons of posts on the syntax to import a JSON file.

My question is where does the JSON file reside?

In my Windows 10 directory, MongoDB is installed in: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`.

I also have a data directory: `C:\data\db`.

I copied a sample JSON file but I don't know where to put this file. No tutorial mentions where these files should reside?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear. However if your target is to import in mongodb a json file, you have to use the following command from your prompt:

```
C:\>mongoimport --db <db_name> --collection <collection_name> --file C:\path\to\your\json\file.json
```

Obviously the previous command works if you have already set mongodb environment variable. Otherwise you have to run the command from `C:\path\to\mongoDB\bin`.

If your target is to export a json file the command is:

```
C:\>mongoexport --db <db_name> --collection <collection_name> --out C:\path\to\your\output file\file.json
```

When one imports a json file it is converted in BSON and all your datas (documents) are saved in `C:\data\db`(in your case). So it's not important where is your json file; after your import what you need is in `C:\data\db`.